# how can I get warnings when importing modules that don't exist

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, eslint

Im using EsLint with VsCode.

How can I have an error appear when trying to import a module that doesn't exist ?

for example

```
import foo from './this-path-doesnt-exist'
```

Should underline in red.
Does this require an eslint plugin ?

Comment: You can also try [flow](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode)

Comment: does flow check for missing modules ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using eslint as your linter, you can use [eslint-plugin-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import) .

> This plugin intends to support linting of ES2015+ (ES6+) import/export
>   syntax, and prevent issues with misspelling of file paths and import
>   names

Answer (score 4):

If you are already not using linter follow below steps:

1. npm install eslint --save-dev
2. npm install eslint-plugin-import --save-dev

then you need to configure

> extends:
>
> - eslint:recommended
> - plugin:import/errors
> - plugin:import/warnings

into your .eslintrc.(yml|json|js) file manually.

If you are already using linter. Skip step one to install eslint.

Comment: way more helpful than the accepted answer, thank you

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the eslint plugin suggested, you can enable semantic checking for a JS file in VS Code by adding `// @ts-check` at the top of the file:

```
// @ts-check
import foo from './this-path-doesnt-exist'
```

[image]

This will enable a number of other checks in the file as well, including type checking, so it may not be appropriate for every code base but it can help catch many common programming mistakes.

[More info about ts-check](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking-and-quick-fixes-for-javascript-files)

Answer (score 0):

And dont forget install extention ESLint, i spent tonn of time on config but problem was in extention.